# Mover vision de personaje de un juego en primera persona

Tags: python

Tengo un script muy simple en Python que debería mover la visión del personaje de cualquier juego en primera persona (Por ejemplo, minecraft, Counter Strike, L4D2, etc), moviendo el mouse a la derecha 5px desde su posición.

Codigo:

```
import pydirectinput
import time

# Pausa para abrir el juego
time.sleep(3)

# Se mueve el mouse 5px a la derecha
pydirectinput.moveRel(5, 0)

print("Fin")
```

El problema está en que se mueve la vision pero incorrectamente, el eje Y lleva la vision hasta abajo por mas que está puesta en cero. Ya intenté también con la función "moveTo".
Intenté usar la librería "pynput" pero no hacía nada, movía el mouse fuera del juego (cuando estaba visible el puntero) pero dentro del juego no ocurría nada.

[Gif de demostración](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/ABLVV86cY2wzFRT5H343YopSTU6-RDJZQOBsMgeRjoNHwDIP9UIH69u8SNxdLOXk-tZC9WkZfpAkYa0yMg7VEy43KwKxzaz2jQoiyw-m3Ld01dxzUoDSoHovnBNSTJXNb5ogfeMhLawHpEQPDr_CcxncH_KBguZOV1Vb0PpqzKaMweyErs4qrgY6Cnhm_5b535EHFEzeesjRBjQ6J0sLmC_iQpGbt4HKID3wgu9pr8DhyfFpMw6mhlIKXymGpb3d9O2d4nUye_BeoRMqQ4W4yeN6J3e5oK7FXgkVgVJbVvUuHL-pKhK4ks2yoRdnul0SbyYHnPovJ31tEu_Q7QVreIwQaTwRjfzcxHGKfki2WDXcK0p1o8MM0E6YXuViI3pJ_IMq6vC1C_o87gwyHzEY_8x0PZ8oTlKKwXnIt8xNhH4JzgdA4BNYyHg0A8r7Ef0zngX-NRelh1l7xrbRxAas0vgGsZ9wzFAgICRHm_A-r2DhxIZOR5vAtoObAakC3oMMxd53vhF1URxWCr-Rv1Ei-6At_nXAAaP3Xz_Yxgqb65MnEi-2ROS4w41ejPeuoA6jNZJJWEyQKOmPfbEKzwd2ypaLKMdkOHy7KZcewENNfKvidNF2Jj28MtMwWuCdJqjA9O4Nn3qR2GSqtRBaAj-ylmw1yIK9R64ps2hQSE0yP3SEA4Ezgu3nnQcV4fXcSBUmj4-uTdeNUOnYHYGRFP4JFAGZJEdjkqH-LcFDkYkyxJBJ1Yc6jtD084fNuysWOjOjAxRgvFapfqk3n3nMn-AhoEKOhKoWZYt2zZIf2gUHlNP9yavZsfCZMjknbEf5BORPie3zL4-rBcgDUOeIQvN3Eci63qABjGogPT21lndg6404aFpr5nOrXBRiHv5pd_7EulinuABhifRBwRGRjwvyj3hSBYvQbLyLjhm0m4ltfX19ElwrVZH22zvDzHGukmcb8FXDpRC3n0ysKJ7O2K_9HJgyJrxIaS7YPLcvlPdb6lM4mzqgSMHq=w1231-h692-s-no-gm?authuser=2)

Comment: No sabría del tema. Pero probaste con darle duración al movimiento? Es decir,  por ejemplo, hacer que moveRel tarde 5 segundos (si es que esta caracteristica existe en pydirectinput), dando una mejor ilusión al juego de un evento de movimiento del mouse?